# how to generate azure devops permissionsreport via API

Tags: azure-devops

MSFT has all this documentation on listing permissionsreports, and even some on creating:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions-report/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

But nowhere can you find anything about how to make the BODY of the POST request to create a new report. If you try to use form-encoding it tells us:

The request indicated a Content-Type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for method type "POST" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json, application/json-patch+json.

But nowhere can you find the format of JSON needed in the body. Has anyone done this or is this just a fake api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body sample to get the report of a repo with [Permissions Report - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions-report/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1):

```
{
    "descriptors": [],
    "reportName": "RepoPermissions",
    "resources": [
        {
            "resourceId": "9cf3xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-370d8cb3xxxx",
            "resourceType": "repo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample result:

[image]

Comment: that's wonderful, thank you. Worked like a champ! For anyone not knowing how to get the resourceid of the repo, it's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP